# updating flows through metadata api

Tags: metadata-api, metadata

```
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();
MetadataService.FlowDefinition flow =
 (MetadataService.FlowDefinition) service.readMetadata('FlowDefinition',
 new String[] { 'test_flow-1' }).getRecords()[0];
 System.debug('fullname ' + flow.activeVersionNumber);
```

Kindly let me know how to activate or deactivate the *activeVersionNumber* field of the FlowDefinition class.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_flowdefinition.htm?search_text=flow